# Windows Phone MultiSelect ListBox selected items

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, listboxitem

For about three hours, I've been trying to get selected indexes of a multiselect listbox. I tried variety of solutions but they don't work. The final thing I've found is the following;

```
            for (int i = 0; i < this.myListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem currentItem = this.myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
                if (currentItem != null && currentItem.IsSelected)
                {
                    ApplicationManager.Instance.getContactManager().addToIndexes(i);
                }

            }
```

This seems to work but when I scroll-down in the list for example, listboxitem of previously selected items returns null. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: you can use selected idex of list box it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you require selected index...

so you have to use List box tap event and than find selected index

for example

```
  private void mylistbox_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {


            List<ClsReportId> lstrptId = new List<ClsReportId>();
            ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;
            int i = lst.SelectedIndex;
            if (lst.SelectedValue == null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ClsGetSubmittedReport cls = (ClsGetSubmittedReport)lst.SelectedValue;
                reportId = cls.ReportId1.ToString();


            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you

Thanks